# Firefox 5 styling checkbox strange background

Tags: css, windows, firefox, firefox-5

The code bellow reproduces a behavior I've come across today that's pretty strange (*only happens on windows*). On hover, Firefox colors the `checkbox` with a black border. As seen on the image.

[image: the black border should not exist]

All other browsers (chrome, safari and all IE's) don't experience similar effect.

Any idea on how I can (keeping the `height` attribute) make Firefox behave?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
        #c-box {
            height: 20px;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
        <input id="c-box" type="checkbox">
        <label for="c-box">this is a checkbox</label>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce anything unusual with the checkbox in firefox 5.0.  Maybe a screenshot?

Comment: @natedavisolds updated an image, thks for the tip.

Comment: I can't reproduce (FF 5.0, OSX).

Comment: @Frankie - I'm (FF 5.0, OSX too). That looks like it is apart of some theme.

Comment: @Ryan Doherty and @natedavisolds I've got hold of a Mac and you guys are correct. I can't reproduce in FF 5 running on OSX, however I can reproduce it in windows XP and Vista. So it's a little FF on Windows kind of thing. Lets hope someone comes along and shares some light on the case. Thks!

Comment: [Can't reproduce on Firefox 5 on Windows 7](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/UxEdG).

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same behavior in Firefox 5 on Windows XP. The only way I was able to eliminate the black background by setting the CSS `Height` value to `auto`, and using `margin-top` to get the checkbox aligned properly instead.

Example:

**Note: In this example, `#c-box` is an `input type="checkbox` element.**

Instead of

```
#c-box {
    height: 20px;
}
```

Use

```
#c-box {
    margin-top: 5px; /* Test to see which margin value matches the look you desire */
    height: auto;
}
```

I know you mentioned that you wish to keep the `height` property, but this solution worked for me without breaking my layout.

Hope that helps! This is my first time actually answering a questions here, after finding countless answers to my own problems. :)